# Rails 4.1.5 assets precompile on production stopping for javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 4.1.5 application, while doing  assets precompile on production it is stopping when comes to javascripts.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Please let me know why it is causing ?

Precompile Log:

```
  laxman@laxman-X551CA:~/rails_projects/monsterquote$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:05.867109 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/416473389-HelveticaNeue-f06f64e96687dba341ba7182dc9d57ef5dde6521a01de19585f3e455dc25109f.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:05.936017 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/416473389-HelveticaNeue-30c8d65d0605a8e24596cbde2cf841e72634da400df7740ae85f5bd55a83ddac.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:06.003129 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/416473389-HelveticaNeue-e3db15cbf154d81eaefa629f916f18a3be053030310da687ad54745d64e19322.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:06.076217 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/416473389-HelveticaNeue-7d64900101d0573dc0ace19bab36c46cfab6f6f72ab11b9354b0d4e041ef27b5.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:06.433093 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/FontAwesome-bdc5d0b9f397be83e886c74b0141d1954aa4384b359dce49829994c4a2e1f7bf.otf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:06.486141 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Bold-23da38f7f3750ac553a675c2b7b7cc6721b08286a0fa95b500c0f41a4a71533b.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:06.615420 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Bold-3057713551ae120e2a6c7c1a1615dac8fac65c7461243cdbd621aa7420637c8d.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.033508 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Bold-38edf86d20e92c62f1661550a935f9a8f573b403ad8472bde8dd8048e6376e1d.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.109507 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Bold-82b1548259f3dfd3656f646361302710785d0a766dcfc97ea276ef9d753c7891.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.168956 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Light-28d4ba558deeaa2a94b86dd0bf7773e18710687244ba7752148e3444e3bf467e.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.223417 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Light-874f05d56c1750ea6a61b5ab82120d7f1569d00f01a99abb98a2eabf68fb9434.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.284949 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Light-f56b81653c7a03ff93b9777933780aff59d01acdb64b49a5ea46c280fefb0d6e.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.293679 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Light-f4e99313f089a97affbe2bab9bd2ee7dd43eb10893e949298bbcaad1e16e5ee2.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.341723 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Thin-210f69f381c0c83480ccd0d7ff442920e4aa6aaac79c44d36eb57d937a8ba0a5.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.402005 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Thin-182b0542e440e1798d9a024a6afa733720d20c25e47f5ed27b25807df75eddf1.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.568669 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Thin-e68287bb4824c09eb39a475ae54cc79f5205e485276ecc17c2daea75aa7e09fe.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.638658 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-Thin-11e480369708ce11f25952118ac7aa68c72a79205b3cdaa68ffaaef2511e78d3.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.670621 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-UltraLight-c59f6cce56db6dcc0ad606e929d6f479ea151fd39d11b747207545aacf8e4297.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.754042 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-UltraLight-d47e1c47c19d64e663e9f816fbad0c1e83d43f58862d5ed82f6834c9f77c4884.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.813381 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-UltraLight-eef4c044d72140267e2c8a431088e5035c8343b0e37cd08fc8696d131e0a39eb.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.843192 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-UltraLight-7fe05d44c327edec681bd9d20453e5b257ed2217a5fa6fc050394294fa430ff8.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.877271 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-f06f64e96687dba341ba7182dc9d57ef5dde6521a01de19585f3e455dc25109f.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.939687 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-64e1fe65fbc20d92515a697b02fc973ec9bdef49c6a7cb16c31a0115050a1a37.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:07.970676 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-e3db15cbf154d81eaefa629f916f18a3be053030310da687ad54745d64e19322.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.007739 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/HelveticaNeue-6e61807da5b5328261aac6645f506f645df42cf426830efbf356f69031929f68.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.177525 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-cbb644d0ee730ea57dd5fbae35ef5ba4a41d57a254a6b1215de5c9ff8a321c2d.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.215052 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-bfdef833219a6edffd9c3cbc28db72739d22bb4d20cc2e2f8d56a7a4d408a206.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.244147 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-9e540a087924a6e64790149d735cac022640e4fa6bff6bd65f5e9f41529bf0b3.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.258645 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-e3870de89716b72cb61a4bba0e17c75783b361cdaba35ea96961c3070bd8ca18.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.262057 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-aadc3580d2b64ff5a7e6f1425587db4e8b033efcbf8f5c332ca52a5ed580c87c.woff2
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.289490 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-13634da87d9e23f8c3ed9108ce1724d183a39ad072e73e1b3d8cbf646d2d0407.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.316901 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-42f60659d265c1a3c30f9fa42abcbb56bd4a53af4d83d316d6dd7a36903c43e5.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.346976 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-e395044093757d82afcb138957d06a1ea9361bdcf0b442d06a18a8051af57456.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.379228 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-a26394f7ede100ca118eff2eda08596275a9839b959c226e15439557a5a80742.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.398855 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fe185d11a49676890d47bb783312a0cda5a44c4039214094e7957b4c040ef11c.woff2
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.424133 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/icomoon-04d6bf9654fba5b7432c38b6194b501676e384c0e5173a23c35381390cb460a8.eot
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.473844 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/icomoon-c13ae5b514151f6c9b5aa48909b59fda1d99f6a4416d2a2f2a2238aa1412f1b8.svg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.504293 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/icomoon-0b702bd2cdced4ba9bd88bc376c1bb4215c63b90b6e2462acd32cd86d67500b6.ttf
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.513894 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/icomoon-d63d0ca4561396330a7cc1d068b83d584067a1761de11ff097f6389f627a65be.woff
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.558742 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/AssortedVeggies4-196e66a84ae4c5155ecbaab58ba48c5a058fd6a50b7959917659090020d65cfc.jpg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.583138 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/Channel_Partner_FPO_Full-a35156d3ab7e2a8d517e3980cc9b76391f04c763e18d90e1f34fbc2477c445d1.jpg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.596900 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/Consultant1_Full-2e4fe6795a7dec7f748fc60295a387711f3f772f0d5a7851fc9023aedfbb0f4c.jpg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.615533 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/Installation_Full-a44990d0db3bb8d84b7559e94cfb08d28361be72aa9a17de38bffcb160f45b79.jpg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.618588 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/Monsterquote_008-ee8d029efef9dd11bf55e4e22a41a833b551e56dea5b0912fea31ec35004e1d4.jpg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.659955 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/benifits-d4ca949f82c6ff263c82c21e9641aa9a0795590297650b5f0c708ce30c049d44.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.685094 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/benifits2-751d36c09f5c3cdd052bfb33d645b896e7bce1a5de2b073aa7824542ace2c89c.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.696135 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/benifits3-34a8497826f5ae080a242a40697e617af3673d671117ef861e6f605b68c4f018.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.721460 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/bwindow_covering-cd6874f9b013c7cce0cdb750332f6e6e2aa839e33bfbfa0a0456bc03f864956a.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.723963 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/divder-35517e8b62b88937f158e8175ed716fb72709f64fa0f9b4e4ca3148f55b3e433.jpg
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.746971 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/easy1-62b3e6968438952d2160bb6345d3e87b50760d6eff725bd898ea924810e9773c.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.749068 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/easy2-ba97293f76d244d6234592e462c355ddbac76013bb7f16e80b25e9edce291c6b.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.766853 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/easy3-c951047e0d497c1f005ec3287d9f7267b62c325cd164ad83e4e095abd41029bd.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.770263 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/gi_icon1-f4aed1125bfb51b0592feb67788b8fb29097482e023051c169e4d3ef90a77754.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.773135 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/gi_icon2-8d346550b365910236b5ffeb26fe0468600cbce4c2f78929e5ba03965568757c.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.794806 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/gi_icon3-ff1c79a86a491147c9db579cbe35bfa3b822772c27f40e955e55d1f4576dbed6.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.797378 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/gi_icon4-d479070cc4044fde6b01e88047e10dae0115c659dfd62a108d8cb27ca57e0095.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.817730 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/gi_icon5-d6bc5884926627d337d08afa9aab5e8d527a48e56d7d7644ed669662221729a3.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.830496 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/gi_icon6-d39231d9a5690b0936531533fc1cc0ca8c3092d5377f20c4dae4afd22f384ab4.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.866891 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/hammer-28b91c22d2dfbe34cac358c75d0056a51750dfe517a8ff1ebee4dda068efd874.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.891495 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/key-b354f951525a76853f6758d6514fe317d99760a3643b9137ecc9c8845e9fb020.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.907550 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/logo-8bf63d80aedac682e13981387195ee462f209cef2c489996d28ed12bd2cf267f.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.911236 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/logo1-096536f6496efb7a30c78251b732b477006e12f2013803d698f13fc5d095c369.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.930904 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/map_dummy-1ce7cc2e0f0c4b4e4b89b0ea4b2fd917acf655d9ff34d3bf4d121a80e71d6756.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:08.959353 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/north_tfb-3c81ecc1aeb24b439303d5614cc365ccaf56f5d9e9cf5090b0b31df4c8dfc318.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.219527 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/pro_img-3e2d16882b136dd6325784d9636a33b5bcbc4b307a9a7e77a8b57cfc802bb9d8.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.245085 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/ribbon-c868a0ee5d93128db7855ae9e367722e05e34c8d8e2107043105959365a5f36d.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.397595 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/solar-2bd535c9115df4f7656e38dd468435045b92e539bfbd37bcf2de4508944204a6.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.440606 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/solar1-89f7bb582f8ab492f4bfe9b943037fab9da758ebb46d71666958e2217a647fe6.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.587520 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/wdoc-c811a11e41c9b347ba8fa95b6beda8190abb21ae916d2da64d4943b00879d7bb.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.608405 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/white_logo-24cae8e474c8ff37724a32d755bd57de962515fda98b2328f00e8cd9de37b200.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.610997 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/window_covering-b0ff3e6ccf74e22625b70ecf49d02926530194a3520293c29a05c4c39d3b451d.png
I, [2015-10-01T17:24:09.613123 #17389]  INFO -- : Writing /home/laxman/rails_projects/monsterquote/public/assets/xlxs-2abe822103dbcc9a7ab43c4e5694089a476e4cd580d0b6f4a91a3b1ee561ad77.png
```

Comment: Please post your logs

Comment: @RajarshiDas, i have updated log. It is stopping when all images, precompiled

Comment: first thing you have to do `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )` and `config.serve_static_assets = true` then run it.  changes should be `production.rb`

Comment: By defauls, precompile only precompiles application.css and application.js, and all non css/js files. You have these files, or modified the asset configuration?

Comment: @All, Please could you guide me to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually two things needed to do in `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )
```

and

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Then run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: I have made above changes. But still it is not working.

Comment: can you please post the path of  js files where you have located those? Please put those in assets javascript and stylesheets folder

Comment: in app/assets/javascripts

Comment: Hi @LaxmanMore can you give me a github link of ur repo so that I can check it on my machine if you have no problem

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I can not disclose project code on git. I got temporarily solution as i have removed config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier and added config.assets.compress = true, it is working for me.